# How can one delete NHibernate objects using a criteria?

Tags: nhibernate, criteria

This must be a simple question. Given a criteria, how one deletes the entities satisfying the criteria?

**The rationale:**

HQL and NH criteria are NHibernate specific constructs and as such they are server side DAL implementation details. I do not want them to "leak" to the client side. So, our client side provides LINQ expressions for the server to process. Up until now the requests where select requests and LINQ to NHibernate dealed with them just fine.

However, there is a need to implement batch delete operation now. As usual, the client side provides a LINQ expression and the server is to delete entities satisfying the expression.
Unfortunately, LINQ to NHibernate is of no help here. The most it can do is translate the given LINQ expression to NHibernate criteria.

Anyway, this is the story. I wish to stress that the client side is unaware of NHibernate at all and I like it to stay this way.

P.S.

I am using NH 2.1

Answer (score 7):

You may use the criteria to select the IDs of your elements, join them in a string and use HQL to delete them?

Something like:

```
public void Delete(ICriteria criteria, string keyName, string tableName)
{
    criteria.setProjection(Projections.Attribute(keyName));
    IList<int> itemIds = criteria.List<int>();

    string collection = string.Join(",", Array.ConvertAll<int, string>(itemIds, Convert.ToString));

    Session.HQL(string.Format("delete from {0} where {1} in ({2})", tableName, keyName, collection);
}
```

This code was not tested or compiled (in particular I'm not sure of the HQL section), but I think that you got the idea: we don't fetch the whole objects thanks to the projection, but only the indices.

Comment: Does it mean two round-trips to the database? If yes, then it is not good enough, because native SQL does it simply in one.

Comment: Still better than N+1… I can't figure a better way using criteria :/

Answer (score 3):

Simply put, up until 2.1.2 you cannot.

However, if you can translate the LINQ expression to HQL (or the ICriteria to HQL) then you can use the overloaded `ISession.Delete()` method which uses a passed HQL string.

Comment: I know I can, but does it not seem strange that LINQ to NHibernate translates LINQ to Criteria instead of to HQL, although the latter is supposed to be more powerful? May be it is not that simple after all. I would love to see a working prototype...

Comment: i wouldn't really say that HQL is more powerful than Criteria, or vice versa. They are just two different constructs, usually with different purposes: HQL for one-off specific queries and criteria for building queries avoiding all the string concatenation hassle, modular support via DetachedCriteria and still being closer to your mapping. The by-example construct is also sweet but in reality rarely used. Anyhow, i'm not using LINQ for nhibernate -yet- so i don't have any examples to give. Nevertheless, until a newer version supports what you want, Criteria are only for select statements

Answer (score -3):

In your repository/dao/persistencemanager/whatever class:

```
public IEnumerable<T> FindAll(DetachedCriteria criteria)

        {

            return criteria.GetExecutableCriteria(Session).List<T>();

        }
```

and then

```
public void Delete(DetachedCriteria criteria)

        {

            foreach (T entity in FindAll(criteria))

            {

                Delete(entity);

            }

        }
```

See Davy Brion's post [Data Access with NHibernate](http://davybrion.com/blog/2008/06/data-access-with-nhibernate/).

*Edit*:

As far as I know, if you want to use Criteria you need to load the objects and iterate over them to delete them. Alternatively use HQL or pass in the SQL to the session.

Comment: I don't like this method though when working with large numbers of objects as it requires fetching all the entities from the database first before they can be deleted.

Comment: This is true, don't you have to use HQL to issue a 'DELETE FROM WHERE' SQL statement?

Comment: Guys, you are not serious. There must be a better way!

Comment: There is - AFAIK not using Criteria though!

Comment: Well, may be it is possible to convert Criteria to HQL?

Comment: @mark: DanB has it right. HQL and Criteria each have its pros and cons. Each has its time and place. For batch updating/deleting use HQL.

Comment: I have added a detailed rationale for wanting what I want in the body of my question.

Answer (score -5):

I know this is an old question but for argument sake; if one uses repository pattern you can declare a delete method which does the following:

```
public void Delete(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
{
    var entities = _session.Query<TEntity>().Where(predicate);
    foreach (var entity in entities)
        _session.Delete(entity);
}
```

Note the code is using expressions in order for repository interface to be generic enough so you can also implement a for example Entity Framework repository.

Comment: Not quite. What you do is use an expression to fetch the entities and then you delete them one by one. This is not deleting entities by expression. What I mean is having a native API that recieves an expression, converts it to the respective delete SQL statement and then deletes all the entities in one go.

Comment: This needs a big warning about how it's not going to be nice when you have a lot of objects.