# delete using criteria query

Tags: nhibernate, criteria

can you delete using criteria query?

I want to do:

DELETE bookmars
WHERE userID = @userID

How can I do this with criteria?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure you can do anything other than query with Criteria, though there is an example of using Criteria to delete already posted on StackOverflow: [How can one delete NHibernate objects using a criteria?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326950/how-can-one-delete-nhibernate-objects-using-a-criteria)

I take it you just want to delete without having to return data.  You might try HQL instead:
http://nhibernate.sourceforge.net/NHibernateEg/NHibernateEg.Tutorial1A.html#NHibernateEg.Tutorial1A-CRUD.Delete

Answer (score -1):

Create a java class:

Here is the code of our java file (`DeleteHQLExample.java`), which we will delete a row from the insurance table using the query `delete from Insurance insurance where id = 2`

Here is the code of delete query: DeleteHQLExample.java

```
package roseindia.tutorial.hibernate;

import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class DeleteHQLExample {
  /**
 * @author ashish baviskar
 */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    Session sess = null;
    try {
      SessionFactory fact = new 
Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
      sess = fact.openSession();
      String hql = "delete from 
Insurance insurance where id = 2";
      Query query = sess.createQuery(hql);
      int row = query.executeUpdate();
      if (row == 0){
        System.out.println("Doesn'
t deleted any row!");
      }
      else{
        System.out.println("Deleted
 Row: " + row);
      }
      sess.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```