# Delete with QueryOver?

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

I would like to improve my code when deleting  a group of objects in NHibernate (V3).
Currently, I iterate on a retrieved collection and I call delete on each object. This generates n+1 SQL statements.

I notice that NHibernate Session provides this method : **Delete(string query)**

By using this method I think I can do the same thing with a single SQL statement.

Do you know if there is a way to combine this method with QueryOver API to avoid HSQL ?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know the only way to do single-shot deletes and updates is using HQL. As a compromise, you might want to take a look at [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326950/how-can-one-delete-nhibernate-objects-using-a-criteria/3068600#3068600).